komacv \cventry with months not only year
I am trying to use komacv to create a nice CV.
But I am failing to add the months to \cventry.
What i tried:
adding it as it is to the entry: \cventry{01/2019--01/2020}
Result:
the months obviously appears but leads to an ugly line break.

Is there an easy fix to have it same line?

Without minimal working example there is nothing I could test to reproduce the problem and nothing I could use to test my ideas. However, section 3.5 of the komacv manual explains the lengths \hintscolwidth, \infocolwidth, and \maincolwidth, that can be used to change the width of the columns and therefore make the first one as wide as you need to prevent the line break.

You can try doing 01/19 -- 01/20 instead. It would look fine if all your dates are formatted consistantly. Another thing to try is reducing the font size. Like \cventry{\small 01/2019--01/2020}.
Take a look into this resume template if you need more customisation options in your resume template.
[It's a suggestion. Can't post it as a comment yet.]

I found meanwhile a german solution which i adjusted to my needs, but your one is an quick and easy workaround.
 inspired from this .sty
\usepackage{times, datetime}
\xdefinecolor{mycolor}{cmyk}{0.9,0.64,0,0.18}
\newcommand* \dateNumMonthDistance{-2.9mm}
\newcommand \fancyDate[2]{%
    \rmfamily{\parbox[t]{0.87cm}{\centering{#2\baselineskip=\dateNumMonthDistance\newline\par\vspace{\dateNumMonthDistance}\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont{\strut\color{mycolor}#1}}}}%
}
\newcommand \fromTo[2]{%
    #1 %extra space
    \hspace{-0.4mm}%
    {%raisebox{-0.35mm}
    {\color{black}--}}\hspace{-0.2mm}%
    \ #2%
}
\newcommand \timespan[4]{%
    \fromTo{%
        \fancyDate{#1}{#2}%
    }{%
        \fancyDate{#3}{#4}%
    }%
}
\def \time[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\timespan{\monthname[#1]}{#2}{\monthname[#3]}{#4}}
\def \from[#1.#2]#3{#3 \fancyDate{\monthname[#1]}{#2}}

Since it was in German i provide a translated version.
usage:
\cventry[hspacingi]{\time[01.2019-02.2020]}{hdegree/job titlei}{hinstitution/employeri}{hlocalizationi}{hgrade/...i}{hcomment/job descriptioni}


Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Could you post the code for your answer, rather than linking to similar code elsewhere? By ensuring that your answer is self-contained, users won't have to dig through the external code to find the part that answers your question.
